# React useState not updating array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to use `useState` in my react functional component to update array of objects but nothing is happening. Here is the code I am trying:

```
const countriesData = [
  { id: 1, name: "India", person: "Harpreet" },
  { id: 2, name: "Aus", person: "Monty" },
  { id: 3, name: "UK", person: "Preet" },
];

ReactDom.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState(countriesData);
  const arr = [{ id: name.length + 1, name: "Pak", person: "Mnm" }];
  const AddMe = () => {
    setName({ ...name, ...arr });
  };
  return (
    <>
      <CountryName data={countriesData} />
      <button onClick={AddMe}> Add me</button>
    </>
  );
}

function CountryName({ data }) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {data.map((element, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <h1>{element.person}</h1>
          <span>from : {element.name}</span>
        </div>
      ))}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

I am a newbie in React. I also tried having `prevState` as `setName` argument and then add like `setName(prevState{ ...pevState, ...arr });` Already had a look on so many sources but no luck. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `name` is an array. In `AddMe` you are trying to merge objects

Comment: You are changing state property name, but you are always looping over countries data. Did you intend to loop over property name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initial data is an array, see in `countriesData` variable, also in `setName` you try to use `{}`.

You should call with `[]` instead of `{}` as:

```
setName([ ...name, ...arr ]);
```

Comment: Tried this but this is also not working. Nothing is happening in browser. No error

Comment: Probably you should use `<CountryName data={name} />` instead of `<CountryName data={countriesData} />`.

Comment: Shouldn't it update the DOM also? Seems like console.log is working with `name` but not changing in DOM

Answer (score 1):

You need to do:

```
setName([ ...name, ...arr ]);
```

or

```
setName((prev) => [...prev, ...arr]);
```

and also update data:

```
<CountryName data={name} />
```

Here is full code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const countriesData = [
  { id: 1, name: "India", person: "Harpreet" },
  { id: 2, name: "Aus", person: "Monty" },
  { id: 3, name: "UK", person: "Preet" }
];
function CountryName({ data }) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {data.map((element, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <h1>{element.person}</h1>
          <span>from : {element.name}</span>
        </div>
      ))}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState(countriesData);

  const arr = [{ id: name.length + 1, name: "Pak", person: "Mnm" }];
  const AddMe = () => {
    setName((prev) => [...prev, ...arr]);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <CountryName data={name} />
      <button onClick={AddMe}> Add me</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-buck-ue9sn?file=/src/App.js:0-826